# Why is CKEditor removing links and attributes

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I have a link with an inline attribute of `style="color: #FF0000;"`. I recently upgraded to latest CKEditor, after years of neglect. Now when I call `CKEDITOR.inline`, it strips all the links.

I found http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dtd-property-S-editable, which doesn't have an `a` in there.

I did `CKEDITOR.dtd.$editable.a = 1;` and it still strips links. What am I missing here? I literally followed the flow from the API `inline` call to that, but it seems that I'm doing something wrong.

**EDIT**
I also find that is removing the `class` attribute from elements. Everything else seems okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the guide about [content filtering (ACF) in CKEditor](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_acf). See also the [working sample in CKEditor SDK](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/acf.html) which shows how ACF works in the default automatic mode and how to adjust it (which is what you need to do in your case).

Comment: And that's what I get for taking years to upgrade. I have to go upgrade some custom plugins too

Comment: That would be explained in [Integraiting plugins with ACF](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/plugin_sdk_integration_with_acf) ;).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```html
CKEDITOR.config.allowedContent = true;
CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty['a'] = false;
CKEDITOR.config.extraAllowedContent = 'a[!href];' + '#';
CKEDITOR.config.protectedSource.push(/<a[^>]*><\/a>/g);
CKEDITOR.config.protectedSource.push(/<span*?[\s\S]*?\/span>/g);
```